# In active Admin gem i want to edit products using custom links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to edit products using custom links in the active Admin gem

I tried

```
column do |show|
  links = ''.html_safe
  links += link_to "Edit", edit_admin_show_path(show)
  links += ' '
  links += link_to "Del", admin_show_path(show), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method =>     :delete
  links
end
```

But i got error 
   missing attribute: category_id
   Extracted source (around line #1):
   insert_tag renderer_for(:edit)